# Web Based MySQL Query Builder?

Tags: mysql, ajax, phpmyadmin

I am fairly new to MySQL, but have improved drastically since first learning over the past few months.

Unfortunately, I am the only one that has any knowledge of MySQL and Databases for the company I work for.

As a result I'm looking for an ad hoc query builder that is web based that essentially will write the query for my co-workers (I'd like it to connect to phpmyadmin.)

I stumbled across this open source project, http://www.ajaxquerybuilder.com/ but I cannot figure out how to connect it to phpmyadmin on my hosting site. (Due to lack of documentation, and more importantly my experience.)

If anyone can offer a suggestion on how to go about doing this, or a similar open source project that could do the job it would be most appreciative. (The program does not have to be in AJAX.)

Comment: I think ajaxquerybuilder is great, it think it might be more easier for you to figure how to configure it

Comment: That's the problem, I'm not sure what file to edit as I have just started. If you have used it before would you be able to direct me on the first step to configuring the download? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A quick guide to run AjaxQueryBuilder in a Linux server:

0) I guess that you already have a mysql server somewhere.

1) Install and configure Apache, Java JDK and then a Tomcat server (I used Tomcat7). Test that it works!

2) Install the mysql-jdbc-connector (Basically copy the .jar file into the Lib folder of Tomcat) - Check the permissions!

3) Copy the AjaxQueryBuilder Files to the ROOT folder (check the permissions again!)

4) Change the settings into the context.xml file in the META-INF folder to your requirements:

```
      url="jdbc:mysql://YOUR_DBSERVER_IP_ADDRESS/YOUR_DB?autoReconnect=true"    
      username="YOUR_DB_USER"
      password="YOUR_DB_USER_PASSWORD"
```

5)Check that all is working!

I had to "follow my intuition" to find this installation steps, so maybe it is not the best way to do it but due to the lack of documentation in the author's site it is the only way I was able to run it.

Answer (score 0):

you can download the database to your own computer / connect remotely to it, and then use programs like [Navicat](https://www.navicat.com/en/products/navicat-for-mysql) or [Toad for MySQL](https://www.quest.com/products/toad-edge/) which is free.